# Detecting when building for userland and kernelland

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I make a small library that will detect when I'm building for userland and when for kernelland and define the right `malloc`/`kmalloc` | `free`/`kfree` methods.

Example:

```
#ifdef __KERNEL__
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

void *new(size_t sz){
#ifdef __KERNEL__
    return kmalloc(sz, GFP_KERNEL);
#else
    return malloc(sz);
#endif
}
```

This works great. Or it used to... I just found that if I `#include <linux/netlink.h>` in my userland app (which is needed for receiving msgs via netlink) `__KERNEL__` gets defined, and my library defines `kmalloc` instead of `malloc`, which then causes errors and I can't compile my app.

Is there any way to reliably detecting when I'm building for kernelland and when for userland? How?

Comment: Works for me. Your headers are broken.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo in my code that was causing all the trouble. Thank!